# Top N per Classification in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, greatest-n-per-group

I'm kinda stuck on this issue. I have several hundreds of a certain model stored in ComsosDb and I can't seem to get the top 5 of each category.

This is the model:

```
"id": "06224840-6b88-4394-9324-4d1628383702",
"name": "Reservation",
"description": null,
"client": null,
"reference": null,
"isMonitoring": false,
"monitoringSince": null,
"hasRiskProfile": false,
"riskProfile": -1,
"monitorFrequency": 0,
"mainBindable": null,
"organizationId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"userId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"createDate": "2020-08-18T11:00:02.5266403Z",
"updateDate": "2020-08-18T11:00:02.5266419Z",
"lastMonitorDate": "2020-08-18T11:00:02.5266427Z"
```

So what i'm trying to do is use C# to get the top 5 from each risk profile where the organizationId matches. GroupBy through LINQ throws an error, same with a row_number() query combined with a PARTITION BY, doesn't seem to work either.
Any way I can get this to work in a single query compatible with cosmos?

EDIT:
What i am trying to achieve in CosmosDb is this roughly:

```
WITH TopEntries AS (
SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                     PARTITION BY [riskProfile] 
                     ORDER BY [updateDate] DESC
               ) AS [ROW NUMBER]
  WHERE [organizationId] = "xyz"
  FROM [reservations]
)
SELECT * FROM TopEntries
WHERE TopEntries.[ROW NUMBER] <= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are trying to achieve is not directly possible through single query in Cosmos DB. There are 2 steps to do this(You can change as per you document sets)

1. Firstly you will have to group by like below:

   `SELECT c.city FROM c where c.org = 'xyz' group by c.city`
2. Then loop through the result one by one from the first query like below:

   `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM C WHERE C.city = 'delhi' order by C.date desc`

You can refer to similar issue here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/38454/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like combining [TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-keywords#top) and [ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-order-by) would do the job. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM c
WHERE c.organizationId = "xyz"
ORDER BY c.riskProfile
```

You can build such queries with parameters in the .NET SDK as in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/Queries/Program.cs#L200).

Comment: I think i may have written it slightly illogically. What i need is the TOP 5 * of each possible risk profile, lets say for organizationId = "xyz" there are several hundred of these models all with among the 6 possible risk profiles, i would need the 5 most recent ones for each risk profile.

Say like this example, but it doesn't work with cosmos:

WITH TOPTEN AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (
        PARTITION BY [group_by_field] 
        order by [prioritise_field]
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM [table_name]
)
SELECT * FROM TOPTEN WHERE RowNo <= 10

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand. Maybe you could update your question with simplified sample input and desired result.